# What happened to the F# Pit project?

Tags: javascript, web, f#

It should have been available once at https://github.com/fsharp/pitfw/ pr pitwf.organd translated F# to Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has pretty much been obsoleted by FunScript (for pure translation to JavaScript) and WebSharper (for a complete web framework including translation to JavaScript).